# How do I write a GCP Dataflow Pipeline in Java?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am unable to find any source code that illustrates the basic setup for a GCP dataflow pipeline. Where can I get started? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several examples of Java (or Python) based GCP Dataflow pipelines. [Here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/WordCount.java) is a simple WordCount example in Java.